# How to create empty columns when selecting columns from a data frame by using NA indexes?

Tags: r, dataframe

here is what I mean:

```
indexes=c(1,NA,4)
```

Now if I do the following I will obviously get an error because of the NA:

```
mpg[,indexes]
```

So for the NA index I need an empty column, in other words I want to see:

```
manufacturer  unknown   year
     audi        ""     1999
     audi        ""     1999
     ...         ...     ...
```

Comment: Why can't the column have a name and just be full of `NA`'s?

Comment: @Paolo Thats a possibilty, but how are you going to get mpg[,indexes] to work with no error?

Comment: Are you trying to add a blank column between two other columns?

Comment: @Paolo Yes, so anywhere that I have an NA index in indexes, I need a blank column.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem - what is your goal with this? What are you going to do with an empty column with no name?

Comment: @Gregor I need the empty column because the order of the indexes matters. In the example above, the third index should be column number four in mpg. If you remove NA, then the second column of the selected dataframe would be number four.

Comment: And what are you doing that the order of the indexes matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tibble:add_column` for this purpose; I use iris database here:

```
df <- iris[,c(1,4)]
V2df <- tibble::add_column(df, unknown = "", .after = 1)
```

You can also use `dplyr::mutate`.

```
require(dplyr)
V2df <- mutate(iris[,c(1,4)], unknown = "")[,c(1, 3, 2)]
```

Output would be:

```
> (head(V2df))

#   Sepal.Length unknown Petal.Width 
# 1          5.1                 0.2 
# 2          4.9                 0.2 
# 3          4.7                 0.2 
# 4          4.6                 0.2 
# 5          5.0                 0.2 
# 6          5.4                 0.4
```